# Is it possible to win Mond Cards?

Tags: mond-cards

I just played [Mond Cards](https://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/630744). I've somewhat regained my sanity, and I'm wondering if it's actually possible to win any of the rounds?

Comment: When you ask if Mond Cards is possible to win, do you mean it is too difficult or do you mean it in a literal sense

Comment: @DavidToh Have you played it? I mean can you win the card game.

Comment: Fast forward to 2022, looks like the site has been acquired and replaced with an online multiplayer game hack site... The latest archived version was [Jan 15, 2018](https://web.archive.org/web/20180115131447/http://gamesforweirdpeople.com:80/mondcards/), but then it was also a Flash game...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple of years of extensive, explorative play-testing, I can confirm that it is impossible to win Mond Cards.